# C++ Qt - QTcpSocket - File not found

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

I am using `Qt` and `QTcpSocket` to create a small chat client/server application.

When I compile my code, the compiler returns the following error:

```
main.cpp:3:22: fatal error: QTcpSocket: No such file or directory
```

This refers to `#include <QTcpSocket>`.

Where is this library located and how can I install it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need

```
QT += network
```

in your .pro file.  Otherwise the module in which those headers are defined/libraries are built won't be loaded.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I still get main.cpp:3:22: fatal error: QTcpSocket: No such file or directory. 

Ah! That's funny! So I modify my .pro, save, and run qmake -project, qmake and make in my terminal, and it changes my .pro back to before!

Comment: I don't have this problem if I compile inside Qt Creator. Closing and restarting it does not affect this issue. Why are my changes not accepted by qmake -project?

Comment: @Bibi541 What?  .pro files aren't auto-generated in any way that I've ever heard.  Something isn't right--you didn't forget to save changes or something simple like that did you?

Comment: What is different when I compile it with Qt Creator? Is it possible that the Makefile does not get updated?

Comment: @Bibi541 I almost always use QtCreator, but when I have compiled/run qmake from the command line, I've never seen what you just described.  I think running qmake should *always* generate a new makefile--that's the point right?  Also auto-generated are the `.pro.user` files, you didn't get mixed up with one of those somehow did you?

Comment: No, because I modified my .pro in Qt Creator, which only shows the .pro in the project. There is no way I changed .pro.user instead. Strange...

Comment: The only reason why I was typing the command line is because somehow my images where not loading when running it with QtCreator, but loading when doing it by hand. Well, I will compile with QtCreator for now, and if I need to load my images, I guess I will come back to stackoverflow and ask :)

Comment: @Bibi541 Yes these kinds of issues with Qt pop up from time to time and can be pretty annoying.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

#### CMake

add to CMakeList.txt

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Network)
target_link_libraries(yourtarget PRIVATE Qt6::Network)
```

#### qmake

```
QT += network
```

Answer (score 0):

As I faced the problem and the obvious solution proposed by the documentation and Matt Phillips seemed not to work, I would add to check **ALL** your .pro files of all your potential subprojects.

As far I'm concerned, addind `QT *= network` did not work in the main .pro and had to be put in the one actually using the QTcpSocket and QTcpServer objects.